# How to generate automatically asn.1 encoded packets?

Tags: generator, packet, asn.1

I want to test my application and I need to generate different load. Application is `SUPL RRLP` protocol parser, I have `ASN.1` specification for this protocol. Packets have a lot of optional fields and number of varians may be over billion - I can't go through all the options manually. I want to automate it.
The first way to generate packets automatically, the other way is to create a lot different value assignments sets and encode each into binary format.
I found some tools, for example [`libtasn`](https://launchpad.net/libtasn1) and [`Asn1Editor`](http://lipingshare.com/Asn1Editor/), but the first one can't parse existing `ASN.1` spec file; the second one can't encode packets by specification.

I'm afraid to create thousandth `ASN.1` parser because I can introduce errors in test process.
I hoped it's easy to find something existing, but... I'm capitulating.
Maybe, someone faced with the same problem on stackowerflow and found the solution? Or know something to recommend. I'll thank you.

Comment: First, could you clarify what you need exactly. Second, have you tried [asn1c](http://lionet.info/asn1c/compiler.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try going to https://asn1.io/asn1playground/ and try your specification there.  You can ask it to generate a sample value for a given ASN.1 type.  You can encode it and edit either the encoded (hex) data, or decoded values to create additional values.

You can also download a free trial of the OSS ASN.1 Tools from http://www.oss.com/asn1/products/asn1-download.html which includes OSS ASN.1 Studio.  This also allows you to generate (and modify) sample values for a given ASN.1 type.

Note that these don't generate thousands of different test values for you automatically, but will parse valid value notation and encode the values for you if you are able to generate valid ASN.1 value notation.